# Update a single node XML file with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this XML file: environment-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<environment>uat</environment>
```

I would like to update the value and have this script.

```
[string]$EnvConfigFileName = ".\environment-config.xml"
$EnvironmentName = 'prod'

[XML]$xmlFileContent = Get-Content $EnvConfigFileName

$xmlNode = $xmlFileContent.SelectSingleNode("/environment")
$xmlNode.Value = $EnvironmentName

$xmlFileContent.Save($EnvConfigFileName)
```

On execution it generates this error: *Exception setting "Value": "Cannot set a value on node type 'Element'."
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot set a value on node type 'Element'.*

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256153/updating-xml-node-even-if-its-empty?rq=1). Basically, use `InnerText` instead of `Value`

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon.  That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the nodes as shown in below code and change the value.

```
[xml]$xmlData = Get-Content $EnvConfigFileName 
$xmlData.environment = "Data"

#Save the file
$xmlData.Save($EnvConfigFileName)
```